# Please help me with this SQL statement problem: how to update all rows in table 1 using sum of diffrent rows from another table

Tags: sql

I need to update table1 only

Table1

```
project_name total_qty
location1
location2
location3
```

Table2

```
project_name   cbm_qty
------------------------
location1        20
location1        20
location2        10
location2        10
```

I was hoping to get a result in table1 like this in table1

```
project_name    total_qty
----------------------------
location1          40
location2          20
location3
```

I want to use update, or insert or union please help thanks

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: You should include create table ddl  and sample inserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
UPDATE t1  
SET total_qty = (SELECT SUM(t2.cbm_qty) FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.project_name = t1.project_name)
FROM Table1 t1
```